# How can I add support for android 4.4 in my android app

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app and I need to run also in older versions of android like android 4.4. I searched a lot but I'm still confusing, I tried something like multindexing but didn't worked. 
My module file looks like this:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "al.sqmo"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It might not be as easy as people make it sound like. The basic idea is right: change the `minSdkVersion`. But then you might run into problems if you've used code that requires later API levels. You might need to change some small things here and there. But you'll find out what's the exact case with your app once you do the change.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I changed minSdkVersion to 19 but the app looks terrible. Some things are not showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set this version in gradle as below

```
minSdkVersion 19
```

That will alow to run app in kitkat.

Let me know for more hlep

Answer (score 1):

To support Android 4.4 you have to set `minSdkVersion` to 19. See the [platform release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms)

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple to do so:

[Check this link out](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4)

Simply change your minimumsdk to 19.